# How can I add different dictionaries to a same list in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add different dictionaries to a same list using a for loop, but I don't know how to generate new dictionaries with each iteration. the file I'm using is of the following format: 
recipe name 
recipe 
recipe name 
recipe 
where recipe is for example "1 cup of flour". there are 10 lines of recipe

I'm trying to add each recipe to a different dictionary, and append those dictionaries to a list. Here's what I have:

```
    fhand = open("recipe.txt").read()
    lines = fhand.split('\n')
    menu = []
    num_of_ingredients = 10
    count = 0
    d = {}
    for line in lines:
        c = count % (num_of_ingredients + 1)
        if c == 0:
            print("Recipe name: ", line)
            menu.append(d)
        else:
            l = line.split(' ')
            print(l)
            servings = l[0]
            line = line[2::] 
            ingredient = line
            print(servings, str(ingredient)) #this line was for me to know how it looks like
            d[ingredient] = servings
       
        count += 1
    menu.append(d)
```

Comment: Move `d = {}` into the for loop instead of before it so you create a new dict on each iteration instead of reusing the same dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your file format is something like this
[if num_of_ingredients = 3]

```
Soup
1 cup flour
2 cup ginger 
3 cup onion
Sandwitch
5 cup bread
3 cup meat
8 cup garlic
```

And what you want is

```
[ {"Recipe name": "Soup", "flour":"1 cup", "ginger": "2  cups", "onion":"3 cup"}, ...]
```

This code should help you then:

```
with open(r"food.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

num_of_ingredients = 3
menu = []

d = {}  #This defined here just to avoid some warning(d being used before being assigned).

for n_line, line in enumerate(lines): 

    if not ( n_line % (num_of_ingredients+1)):    #enumerate is far better choice than counting manually
        if (n_line != 0) :
            menu.append(d)       #dictionary will be appended , only when it is time to assign a new recipe(but you know that already)
        d = {}               #Here comes the important part(your answer), This is how you should assign new empty dict, everytime a new list item is initiated.
        d["Recipe name"] = line

    else:
        ingredient = ' '.join(line.split()[2:])
        servings = ' '.join(line.split()[:2])
        d[ingredient] = servings
menu.append(d)      #this last append is beacuse after the last iteration, we won't go back to the if block, to append rhe last list item.

print(menu)
```

If I have something wrong in my assumptions, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

two things: first you have to create the dictionary inside your loop, so, for each loop, it will be a new dictionary (the way you did you are only changing the same dictionary d); second, are you sure your if and else condition are doing exactly what you want? Because it seems that `c = count % (num_of_ingredients + 1)` will be always different than zero except when `count=0`

[edited]

use `menu.append({})` instead of `menu.append(d)` in your if condition to create a new dictionary, and in order to edit it use `menu[-1][ingredient] = servings` so you will change the last dictionary in the menu

Comment: `count % (num_of_ingredients + 1)` will be zero on the first line of input and then on every 11th line.

Comment: yes but there are 10 lines only

Comment: I'm not sure that is true. The OP says "there are 10 lines of recipe", but the lines above that statement that show the file format show the word "recipe" repeated multiple times. I interpret this to mean that **each recipe** has a "recipe name" and then 10 lines.

Comment: ah, in this case d={} should be inside the if condition, otherwise it will create a new dictionary for each recipe line

Comment: I've edited my answer based on Code-Apprentice comment. See if this trick solves your problem.